# What IC is "293" "GZ624"?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, identification

I am trying to identify this IC: [image: Unidentified IC]

I have tried google and a bunch of component shops but I can't find the number anywhere. As far as I can tell, on the chip it has 293 GZ624 and it is made by ST. Is there anyone who has come across this before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My first guess would be that it is an [LM293 dual voltage comparator](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/b4/cc/cf/13/18/28/44/f5/CD00000465/files/CD00000465.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000465.pdf).

The pin count is correct, the package style is correct, and there is a via coming off of pin 8 (Vcc on the LM293) to an internal layer, which would make sense if it was connecting to a Vcc plane. It would be helpful to see more of the circuit, but I expect this might be your best bet.

Comment: The package marking specified on pg.18 of the datasheet supports this.